# Partial views with JavaScript in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have multiple partial blade files that all require just a little bit of JavaScript. Ideally I'd like the partial to load the JS it needs and the normal JS wouldn't include it. I know you can load it all into one big JS file, but I am wondering if there is a way to have a more elegant solution.

I'd like the solution below to work for multiple files (it works for one, but not n. The first partial blade encounters is used due to blade's rendering engine).

**test.page.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('title', 'Poses')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @include('test.partial.one')
            @include('test.partial.two')
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
@section('javascript')
    @include('test.partial.one')
    @include('test.partial.two')
@stop
```

**partial test.partial.one.blade.php**

```
@section('content')

    <h1>One</h1>

@stop

@section('javascript')

    <script>Scripts from one</script>

@stop
```

**partial test.partial.two.blade.php**

```
@section('content')

    <h1>Two</h1>

@stop

@section('javascript')

    <script>Scripts from two</script>

@stop
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution to your problem is the `@parent` directive, which you have to use in your `javascript` sections.

test.page.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.default')
@section('title', 'Poses')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @include('test.partial.one')
            @include('test.partial.two')
        </div>
    </div>
@stop

@yield('javascript')
```

test.partial.one.blade.php

```
@section('content')
    <h1>One</h1>
@stop

@section('javascript')
    <script>Scripts from one</script>
    @parent
@stop
```

test.partial.two.blade.php

```
@section('content')
    <h1>Two</h1>
@stop

@section('javascript')
    <script>Scripts from two</script>
    @parent
@stop
```

For further reference: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates