# Including Sub-Views in Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to include two sub-views ( 'login' and 'register' ) in the 'home' view which is like this:

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')

    @include('auth.login')
        <hr>
    @include('auth.register')

@endsection
```

And the 'login' and 'register' views:

```
//register.blade.php

@extends('master')

@section('content')

{!! Form::open() !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email Address') !!}
        {!! Form::email('email', null, 
            ['class' => 'form-control', 
             'placeholder' => 'Email Address', 
             'required' => true]) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('password', 'Password') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password', 
            ['class' => 'form-control',
             'placeholder' => 'Password', 
             'required' => true]) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            {!! Form::checkbox('remember', null, []) !!}
            Remeber Me
        </label>
    </div>

    {!! Form::submit('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}

@endsection
```

---

```
//login.blade.php
@extends('master')

@section('content')

{!! Form::open() !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email Address') !!}
        {!! Form::email('email', null, 
            ['class' => 'form-control', 
             'placeholder' => 'Email Address', 
             'required' => true]) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('password', 'Password') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password', 
            ['class' => 'form-control', 
             'placeholder' => 'Password', 
             'required' => true]) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            {!! Form::checkbox('remember', null, []) !!}
            Remeber Me
        </label>
    </div>

    {!! Form::submit('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}

@endsection
```

I've tried removing the master extension from the sub-views but it didn't work. Only one sub-view is being rendered. I can't figure out, why that's happening?

Answer (score 0):

**main.blade.php**

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')

    @include('auth.login')
        <hr>
    @include('auth.register')

@endsection
```

For the sub views you have to remove the `@extends('master')`. Then you have two options I can think of.

You can add the `@parent` directive.

**register.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
{!! Form::open() !!}

...

    {!! Form::submit('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
@parent
@endsection
```

**login.blade.php**

```
@section('content')

{!! Form::open() !!}

...

{!! Form::close() !!}
@parent
@endsection
```

or remove the sections.

**register.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open() !!}

...

    {!! Form::submit('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**login.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open() !!}

...

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271376/partial-views-with-javascript-in-laravel-5).

---

**Updated per comments**

If you need to access the pages separately you could extract the form code into partials and include them where needed.

**main.blade.php**

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')

    @include('auth.partials.login')
        <hr>
    @include('auth.partials.register')

@endsection
```

Setup you stand alone pages.

**auth/register.blade.php**

```
@section('content')

    @include('auth.partials.register')

@endsection
```

**auth/login.blade.php**

```
@section('content')

    @include('auth.partials.login')

@endsection
```

Setup your partials

**auth/partials/register.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open() !!}

...

{!! Form::submit('Login', ['class' => 'btn btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**auth/partials/login.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open() !!}

...

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: I also want login and signup as separate views.

Comment: @HammadAhmed Updated the answer per your comments.

Comment: Can't it be more simpler